# How to plot 2 variables on top of each other in ggplot r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to ask how I can plot multiple variables in R so I can obtain plot like this:

[image]

On the x axis we have particular months, on y some counting variable (count is already in the data), on the legends we have 5 quantiles, but additionally I want to have 1 more variable in another legend, which is year. Ideally I would want to have It in alpha parameter, so the 5 bars and 8 months stay the same and we see 2 bars on top of each other and they are a bit transparent with 2 colors for other years (I just have 2 year) . We have this counting on top of the bars, so we can compare each quantile from 2 years.

I already wrote this, but it's plotting the data not 5 columns for each month, but stacking the quantiles in 1 bar instead.

```
ggplot(data, aes(month, sum, fill = year, alpha = quantiles)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", alpha = 0.5) +
   geom_text(aes(label = round(sum, digits = 3)), position = position_dodge(width = 1), na.rm = TRUE) +
   scale_x_continuous(labels=month, breaks =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

Answer (score 3):

From a data visualization point of view, having all these labels on your plot is going to make it look messy and unprofessional. If you need to display all the numbers, consider using a table instead, or a table alongside your plot.

However, you can achieve what you asked for like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(quantiles, sum, fill = factor(year))) +   
  geom_col(position = "stack") +   
  geom_text(aes(label = round(sum), group = year), vjust = -0.2, 
            hjust = 0, angle = 45,
            position = position_stack(), na.rm = TRUE) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.1, 0.3)) +
  facet_grid(.~month, switch = "x") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  labs(fill = "Year", x = "Month") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightblue", "orange")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously, we don't have your data, but I created a little data set with the same structure as yours to creste the above plot.

```r
set.seed(1)

data <- data.frame(month = rep(rep(1:8, each = 5), 2),
                   year = rep(2021:2022, each = 40),
                   quantiles = rep(1:5, 16),
                   sum = rnorm(80, 5000, 750))
```

Comment: Ah had posted an answer but this one's better!

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer- really helpful. Although I wanted a slightly different output- its was hard to explain in the description. Ideally I wanted the bars starting in the same point- at 0 at x axis and then 2022 on top of 2022 and both transparent, so that the difference will be slightly less dense on top (with labels of sum in the ending of each bar), instead of 2 bars summed with each other on top of each other. Are you familiar with the resolution like that? One more time sorry- I just didn't explain it well

Comment: @Fendi I thought you might mean that. However, when we do this, the end result looks much worse.  You can have a look by changing the `position = 'stack'` to `position = 'identity'` in `geom_col` and removing the `position =  position_stack()` inside `geom_text`. You will also need to add `alpha = 0.5` inside `geom_col`. The end result is just a mess of indistinct colours and clashing text labels, and is not a good choice for presenting your data.